# return results array from class to other class java

Tags: java, database, jdbc, connection, derby

First I'm sorry about my English,
I'm new on Java programing and I'm trying to get result values from DB. class to another class on jdbc derby this is my code:

```
package myjavaproject;

import java.sql.*;

public class Db {

private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/hotels;create=true";
private static String tableName = "users";
// jdbc Connection
private static Connection conn = null;
private static Statement stmt = null;
public String data = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createConnection();
    shutdown();
}

private static void createConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
        //Get a connection
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
    }
    catch (Exception except) {
        except.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

public static String selectUsers() {
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from " + tableName);
        Results name = new Results();
        if(results.next()){
            name.setName(results.getString("name"));
            String rs = results.getString("name");
            //return rs;
        }


        results.close();
        stmt.close();
    } 
    catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
        sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static void shutdown() {
    try {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL + ";shutdown=true");
            conn.close();
        }
    } 
    catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You want to return data from ? to ?

Comment: yes, exactly, I want to get result from one class to another one example Db.java where the code to connect to the database and query and user.java where I can get results, thanks to replay

Comment: In this case, your User.java class must make a call to DB.java class, through an object of the latter !

Comment: The problem is that I can't return array result I have seen many answers about ArrayList, I don't have any experience on Java, but en PHP example I just do return results [].

Answer (score 1):

Really what you probably want is a service class that acts as a controller to get everything configured for you.

something like:

```
public class Service() {
   private Db databaseConnection;
   private List<User> users;

   public Service() {
      databaseConnection = new Db();
   }

   public List<Users> getUsers() {
        users = new ArrayList<User>();
        rs = databaseConnection.selectUsers(); //you'd need to change this to return the list of users, or to return the result set
        if (rs != null && rs.size() > 0) {
            while(rs.hasNext()) {
                 User aUser = new User();
                 aUser.setName(rs.next().get("Name")); //pseudo-code
                 users.add(aUser);
            }
        }
        return users;
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to use a list, you could use User[] users = new User[rs.size()]; and then return an array of User instead of a List<Use>.

Comment: @UncleIeoh thank you for your answer. but do you know any tutorial can help me i don't want to lose you time

Comment: How can I return a result from Query that I can collect from other class.

Comment: I can't think of any nice tutorials -- sorry.

Comment: Ok I can get results but the error said that it not String instance of void, have you any idea.

Comment: it's probably complaining about a return type.  You are returning a String when you've said void or vice versa

Comment: +1, thanks for your time again. That's exactly what happens now I can get results but I don't know the way to receive it from others because it's void.

Comment: I suggest finding a little application that is pre-configured with some of these basics in place.  I'm sure there's some maven plugin somewhere that'll create you a simple base project to mess with.